# Keras plot_model does not show the connections appropriately

Tags: keras, huggingface-transformers

In the following code, we expect a connection from `input_token` and `masked_token` to the `TFDistilBertModel`.

```
from transformers import TFAutoModel
import tensorflow as tf

def build_classifier_model():
   bert = TFAutoModel.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased')
   input_ids_in = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(128,), name='input_token', dtype='int32')
   input_masks_in = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(128,), name='masked_token', dtype='int32') 

   embedding_layer = bert(input_ids_in, attention_mask=input_masks_in)[0]
   model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[input_ids_in, input_masks_in], outputs=embedding_layer)

   for layer in model.layers[:3]:
     layer.trainable = False
   return model

model = build_classifier_model()

tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model)
```

However, I get the following plot. Is there something wrong in my code or it is an error with keras?

[image]

Comment: Could you find any answer to your question? I have the same problem.